# Creating snapshot API got an error of 500-Internal Server Error

Tags: elasticsearch

We are new to the [snapshot-and-restore](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/put-snapshot-repo-api.html#put-snapshot-repo-api) function of Elasticsearch. Following the example below, we are trying to create a snapshot repository with the Console of Dev Tools.

The Elasticsearch server under test runs as a Docker container, and services runs with username `elasticsearch`. So, we created a folder in the user's home directory, `/usr/share/elasticsearch/my_backup_location` in the container.

```bash
PUT /_snapshot/my_backup
{
  "type": "fs",
  "settings": {
    "location": "/usr/share/elasticsearch/my_backup_location"
  }
}
```

However, the command did not work, and it got a "500-Internal Server Error" with the following error message:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "repository_exception",
        "reason": "[my_backup] location [/usr/share/elasticsearch/my_backup_location] doesn't match any of the locations specified by path.repo because this setting is empty"
      }
    ],
    "type": "repository_exception",
    "reason": "[my_backup] failed to create repository",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "repository_exception",
      "reason": "[my_backup] location [/usr/share/elasticsearch/my_backup_location] doesn't match any of the locations specified by path.repo because this setting is empty"
    }
  },
  "status": 500
}
```

We wonder if we are missing anything in the test above and will highly appreciate any hints and suggestions.

Please let us know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is

> [my_backup] location [/usr/share/elasticsearch/my_backup_location] doesn't match any of the locations specified by path.repo because this setting is empty

So in your `elasticsearch.yml` configuration file, you need to add this line:

```
path.repo: /usr/share/elasticsearch/my_backup_location
```

Comment: Yes, we resolved the issue by 1) editing the `elasticsearch.yml` in the container, then 2) re-starting the elasticsearch container.